# Dynamically invoke a dll in sharepoint

Tags: c#, reflection, sharepoint-2007

How to invoke a dll that is dynamically created (during runtime) in a sharepoint site? i am recieving an error that i dont have the load permissions.
Any help on this will be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

while the dll is created dynamically in the solution set the property of the copmileroptions "generateinmemory=true . once the dll is created this way then the dynamically created dll can be used in the sharepoint proj without deploying the dll to the GAC or adding the dll name to the  safecontrollist in the web.config of the sharepoint site .